# PHP Symfony - Connection was reset (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, apache, symfony1, httpd.conf

I configured Symfony 1.4 on Windows. My Server is Wamp.

I' m using tutorial from Symfony Site. My httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "C:\dev\sfproject\web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "C:\dev\sfproject\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf c:\dev\sfproject\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf
  <Directory "c:\dev\sfproject\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that when i trying show: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php/
I get: **Connection was reset**.

Other informations about my config:
*I installed symfony in my project directory
*I have windows 8 (Customer Preview Version)
*My WAMP server run correct (green icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running php symfony cc from cmd in your project. If you get an error containing something about CLI you need to install XAMP or reinstall your WAMP php library

Comment: Yes I have error with CLI :( But I tried reinstall WAMP 3 times and the same.

Comment: Big Thanks ! :) Installed XAMP and it' s works. Still don' t know what was wrong in wamp, but it' s good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look here i think the problem is that you haven't defined a ServerName or you have dublicate entrys for the VHost:

https://serverfault.com/questions/86972/the-connection-was-reset

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don' t know anything in this topic. I have only one virtual host and it' s work with normal php files. I think it' s not that problem. I tried give a name but the same result.